# Usage of --reset and register tag in Docker run command?

Tags: docker, qemu

I am new to Docker and Qemu.  I am thinking about using [this Qemu](https://github.com/multiarch/qemu-user-static/blob/master/README.md)

I am trying to understand the following command:

```
docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static:register --reset
```

Why did they include `--reset`, and what significance does the `register` tag have?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `--reset` it means what they wrote in the [ReadMe](https://github.com/multiarch/qemu-user-static/blob/master/README.md#binfmt_misc-register): *Remove all registered binfmt_misc before*, so by looking into `register.sh` you can see the following:

```
if [ "${1}" = "--reset" ]; then
    shift
    find /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc -type f -name 'qemu-*' -exec sh -c 'echo -1 > {}' \;
fi
```

So when you pass `--reset` it will disable everything related to qemu and the `register` tag itself i guess they use to enable `binfmt_misc` before using Qemu because if it was not found the container will fail:

```
if [ ! -d /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc ]; then
    echo "No binfmt support in the kernel."
    echo "  Try: '/sbin/modprobe binfmt_misc' from the host"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Thank you @Mostafa Hussein!